# Seprate values from mysql column data with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to echo a column value, which is working fine, But I want to break the line when there is a comma came in, so I want to get each value in one line. ipd_medicine_name column has multiple values in it, which are separated by ' , ' (comma)

```
$records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ipd_medicine_name FROM `ipd_patients` WHERE ipd_patientid = ".$_GET['ipd_patientid']." "); 
 while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
    {
      echo  " <p>"$data['ipd_medicine_name']."</p>  ";
    }   
?>
```

Comment: search for `explode()` and `implode()` functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo '<p>' . str_replace(',', '<br />', $data['ipd_medicine_name']) . '</p>';
```